# Can the same thread be used by multiple web requests when one request is in an I/O-bound work state?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, .net-core, async-await

In .NET Core, let's say we have a web API endpoint which triggers an `async/await` operation because there is some I/O work to be done.

Since we're using `async/await`, the thread that handles this first request is freed up when I/O work starts.

What if that I/O work takes some time, all other threads are busy(thread pool is full) and a new request comes ? Is it possible for the freed up thread which normally waits for the I/O operation, to pickup work for the new request ?

Comment: As I understand it, that is exactly the point of async: freeing up threads that would otherwise be waiting, so they can be used to handle other requests. See also https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Since we're using async/await, the thread that handles this first request is freed up when I/O work starts.

Yes. Once the top-level handler does an `await`, that request thread is returned to the thread pool.

> What if that I/O work takes some time, all other threads are busy(thread pool is full) and a new request comes ?

If all the request threads are busy, then the request sits in a queue waiting for a free thread.

> Is it possible for the freed up thread which normally waits for the I/O operation, to pickup work for the new request ?

It's not clear what you mean by this "thread which normally waits for the I/O operation". The I/O operation was asynchronous, so the request thread has been returned to the thread pool, and [there is no thread waiting for the I/O operation](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html).

You might find [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/october/async-programming-introduction-to-async-await-on-asp-net) helpful; the details do not apply to ASP.NET Core, but the general concepts do (synchronous vs asynchronous requests, threads "doing" I/O, and thread pool vs async).

Comment: _'It's not clear what you mean by this "thread which normally waits for the I/O operation".'_ I think OP means that in a pre-async-world the thread would be blocked by any synchronous IO operation and therefore not available to do other stuff.